# My Rails API endpoint takes a Host value, want to be able to get domain, subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My controller action receives a hostname like:

```
/customer?hostname=hello.example.com
```

Now in my action I have this:

```
def customer
  hostname = params[:hostname]
end
```

I want to be somehow parse this hostname the same way Rails does, so I can do something like:

```
request.domain
request.subdomain
request.host
```

It seems the the ActionDispatch Url.rb is the module that does the logic aroudn this, but not sure how I can tap into this?

I would want something like this:

```
  url = ActionDispatch::abc(hostname)

  url.domain
  url.subdomain
  url.host
```

What class/methods should I be using here?

Reference:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/url.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
class UrlParser
  include ActionDispatch::Http::URL

  def initialize(url)
    @_url = url
  end

  # Don't forget to override this method!
  def raw_host_with_port
    @_url
  end
end

## Example usage:

url = UrlParser.new 'sub.example.com:8080'

url.subdomain     # => 'sub'
url.domain        # => 'example.com'
url.port          # => '8080'
```

Comment: why the comment about overriding method?

Comment: why @_url, does dispatcher expect that var?

Comment: Nope, that actually can be whatever you want. I just named it `@_url`, you can name it anything. As far as you are returning the URL that needs to be parsed from the `raw_host_with_port` method.